# explorer.exe can't modify directories, cmd.exe can

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have 64-bit Windows 10 Pro, upgraded from Windows 7. My problem is that my windows explorer cannot find my directories if it would need to move or rename them. It can *create* directories, but they always end up having name "New Folder", and I get this:
[image: screenshot]

If I use cmd.exe, I can move and rename my directories just fine.

Apparently explorer.exe always first creates them with name "New Folder" and then renames it and renaming fails.

I have three hard drives: 500GB SSD drive, and 3TB and 1TB HDD drives. The behaviour is identical with directories in all these three drives.

Comment: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-rename-move-folders-windows-10/

Comment: @RobertHarvey well now I feel silly. That worked. Thank you. Want to add it as an answer?

Comment: @eis Answer already exists

Comment: @Ramhound well, that's for Windows 8.1 and the registry entries seem to be windows version specific as well, so answer working for that question won't work (and is actually harmful) here. But you're right in that it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: (though for me I couldn't even create them or delete them. In that thread there apparently is problem only with renaming)

Comment: ...and in that thread the question says explicitly that registry fix didn't help him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @robert-harvey:s link, the problem was due to missing FolderDescriptions registry entries.

I was able to fix it by using registry entries in the download of this page: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-rename-move-folders-windows-10/